# Bosch Dishwasher Leaking from the front

Tags: leak, dishwasher

Our dishwasher is leaking from the front door area. It's unclear exactly where the leak is but the water is streaming down the left side of the door (see photo). About 2 pints of water comes out each run -- it drips fairly regularly. When I open the door, the pan is full of water (maybe 0.5 - 1" deep) and the leaking stops. It only seems to leak when the machine is actively running with the door closed. I ran a dishwasher cleaning pellet recently but other than that I haven't done any maintenance recently.

Are there common reasons for such leaking? Are there other details I can post to help diagnose the issue?

[image]

Comment: Two things would help us greatly: A photo showing the whole scene instead of just a blank panel, and the model number of your unit. Please revise.

Comment: The door seal should be checked for any damage or stuff struck on it preventing a good seal.